# Dynamic module import in a class hierarchy

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two python libraries, let's call them `lib` and `extended_lib`, that provide a very similar public API. To be more specific, `extended_lib` enriches the API of `lib` with new features and functionality; it also modifies the behavior of some functions that are also provided in `lib` (e.g. `get_version()`).

I have a pair of classes `LibWrapper` and `ExtendedLibWrapper`, the latter being a sub-class of the former, that dynamically load the corresponding module and save its reference within an instance variable (i.e. `self._lib`).

I have a class `Base` that inherits from `LibWrapper` and a class `Derived` that inherits from both `Base` and `ExtendedLibWrapper`. The class `Base` exposes the functionalities provided by `lib`. The class `Derived` inherits all these functions and exposes also the functionalities provided by `extended_lib`.

This setup is meant to allow `Derived` to inherit, without code duplication, the functionality provided by `Base`.

I designed the `LibWrapper` and `ExtendedLibWrapper` as an independent hierarchy of classes because there are multiple `Base`/`Derived` pairs.

**Example:**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import importlib

class LibWrapper():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._lib = self.get_lib()

    def get_lib(self):
        return importlib.import_module("lib")


class ExtendedLibWrapper(LibWrapper):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExtendedLibWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_lib(self):
        return importlib.import_module("extended_lib")


class Base(LibWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Base, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_version(self):
        return self._lib.get_version()

    def print_version(self):
        print("Base class:\n\t" + self.get_version())



class Derived(Base, ExtendedLibWrapper):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Derived, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def print_version(self):
        print("Derived class:\n\t" + self.get_version())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    base = Base()
    base.print_version()

    derived = Derived()
    derived.print_version()
```

The output is:

```bsh
~$ ./test.py
Base class:
    Lib Version
Derived class:
    Extended Lib Version
```

**Question(s):**

- coming from a different software development experience (`c++`), I would like to ask: *is this pythonic?*
- is there a better, more robust or easily extensible, setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely pythonic: implementing lib wrappers allows one to easily include additional features in wrapper classes, as a complement to pure import. So it is both concise and versatile.

As you are working with Python 3 (according to the shebang), you may use the simplified form for `super()`:

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

instead of

```
super(ExtendedLibWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works even with multiple inheritance.